# WebGL Background Colour

Tags: canvas, webgl

We're currently using this smoke animation here:
https://codepen.io/Irehan/pen/YgyozL

This is the code we've been trying to amend to change the background colour:

```
gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

We've tweaked the config values slightly to get it running well and it's working really nicely.

The last thing we have to do is change the background colour from #000 to #1a1422 however, I can't seem to get it working despite changing the clearColor line to a different hue.

Comment: You need to update the `displayShader` output, and replicate [the license](https://codepen.io/amiedd/details/xQQJaO).

Answer (score 0):

As LJ said in the comment, you need to modify the `displayShader` output and add to the texture the color you want:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUv) + vec4(0.10, 0.07, 0.13, 1.0);
```

To convert HEX to RGB 0-1 you can use this [tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html).